# Why cant const references be returned in the same way as pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers

If we return pointers from functions, we can write either

```
const X* f();
```

or

```
X* const f();
```

,in this way controlling whether the pointer can be reassigned or if the class can be modified internally. But when returning references, these two seems to have the same meaning:

```
const X& f();
X& const f();
```

It seems impossible to return a reference where you can modify X, but not re-assign it?  And if it is indeed impossible, why should we ever return references when pointers seem potent in this area?

UPDATE: As been pointed out, references cannot be reassigned. However this makes me even more bewildered, as the following code prints 33 55, not 33 33 as I would expect. How does that match with that references cannot be reassigned?

```
struct X
{
   X(int i_) { i = i_;} 
   int i;
};

struct Y
{
    X& get2() {tmp2 = new X(55); return *tmp2;} 
    X& get() {tmp = new X(33); return *tmp;}    
    void print () {cout << tmp->i << endl;}
    X* tmp;
    X* tmp2;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Y y;    
    X& tmp2 = y.get2();
    X& tmp = y.get();       
    y.print();
    tmp = tmp2;
    y.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `X& const f();` is nonsense see: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html

Comment: Why do you expect "33 33", you've assigned `tmp2` to `tmp`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**It seems impossible to return a reference where you can modify X, but not re-assign it?**

References can never be re-assigned. They keep referring the same referent to which they are bound at initialization.

**why should we ever return references when pointers seem potent in this area?**

Reference usage is more intuitive, the caller of functions can use references simply like variables unlike pointers where the user has to deal with the dereferencing etc.

Comment: Another good reason for returning references over pointers is that it will point to a valid object/function since null references are not allowed (in sensible C++). Hence calling code does not have to handle a NULL case and you avoid problems like dereferencing a NULL pointer. Of course, if your calling code knows a-priori that the function will never return a NULL pointer, it doesn't need to worry about the NULL case, however, using a reference instead "documents" this guarantee explicitly.

Comment: @PreetKukreti: Yes, thats true indeed.

Comment: Ok, I updated my question with what I wouldnt excpect if references were non-reassignable

Comment: @PreetKukreti: Well sure null wont be returned true, but still what the reference points at could be destroyed at a later occasion, so some sort of checking is normally still needed, right? If you return a pointer, checking if it is null is a good way to know if the object is still valid, in my opinion.

Comment: @Frank you would expect (especially in a single-threaded program) that a reference returned by a function does not point to stale data because usually you use that reference straight away. Storing a reference for a long lifespan for multiple later uses presents the same dangling pointer problems as a pointer would have. I hope you realise that if a pointer's target memory has in fact moved or been freed, checking that the pointer is not NULL doesn't say anything about the validity of the pointer; This is because pointers (or references) aren't automatically updated if the target is moved/freed

Comment: @PreetKukreti: Im aware of that ofcourse, but still its quite common to set a pointer to null to mark when the object has been deleted. However what I meant was just that I dont think the benefit of knowing that the reference cant point to null is not so big, and that there is no guarantee that the reference will point to "a valid object", as you proposed.

Comment: @Frank: The benifit lies in the fact the caller need not check for `NULL`, as the referene cannot be `NULL`,If a reference is `NULL`then the program is already ill-formed and has caused an UB,what happens after the UB is completely unpredicatable.So the user of the function can safely assume a reference can't be `NULL` while if it is a pointer the user needs to implement the `NULL` check,unless ofcourse the function says it won't return a `NULL` ever.

Comment: @Frank you've obviously misunderstood the entire point of my first comment. By using a reference as the return type of a function, you can use it as a "soft-guarantee" that the value is always a valid one. A pointer does not provide this semantic. In both cases (pointer or reference), the returned memory address may in fact be invalid; but if it is invalid, that is the fault of the called function - You would expect after calling a function and using its return reference straight away that it would not point to invalid memory. A lot of the advantage is semantic, not mechanical.

Comment: @PreetKukreti: I might be wrong but what I mean is we must still have some code to handle the exact same thing as a returned null, even in the reference case. Lets say someone calls const X& getSomeInternal(), before/after this internal is available. Then instead we must throw an exception or something similar to signal it is not available. And then we must add error handling for this as well, even though in this case it does not mean comparing the pointer to null. Of course, if the program is built correctly this need may never arise, but again its the same case with the pointers.

Comment: @Frank yes! the entire point is that you might then have one of two versions: `X* getSomeInternal()` which can return an uninitialised pointer, or `X& getSomeInternal()` which guarantees that the returned value is valid. The idea is to define your interface based on what postconditions your functions can guarantee. If your function might not be able to always return a valid resource, return a pointer (with NULL signalling it is invalid). Else use a reference. Its a way of documenting your code and avoiding ambiguity; *it provides semantic value much the same way as good variable naming does*.

Comment: @PreetKukreti: Alright, so for me it was not clear from your first comment that what you meant was "return a reference only if you know  its valid". If you use it in this way I totally agree with you, it has an added value over returning a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Your first two examples are NOT the same. You probably meant

```
const X* f();
X const* f();
```

and you can in fact write the same with references:

```
const X& f();
X const& f();
```

The declaration `X* const f();` doesn't make a lot of sense. You can't change the returned pointer anyway. It's just a value. You can either use the value (i.e. `f()->foo()`) or store it (i.e. `X* copy = f();`). And if you store the value, then the const-ness depends only on the variable in which you stored the value, not the value itself. Compare `int x  = 4;` - `x` doesn't become const just because `4` is a constant.

Answer (score 2):

Re the update question: When you do 
    tmp = tmp2;
in the main function, you are not assigning the reference to tmp2 to tmp. Rather, you are copying the whole object.

To see this, give X copy constructor that prints something. Something like this should work:

```
X(X& that)
{
    std::cout << "X is being copied" << std::endl;
    *this = that;
}
```

Comment: Thanx I finally got what was happening. I should have printed the pointer values instead, then it would have been obvious :)

Answer (score 0):

> It seems impossible to return a reference where you can modify X, but not re-assign it?

Indeed. A reference is an alias for a variable, and cannot be reseated (ie, be changed to alias another variable).

> And if it is indeed impossible, why should we ever return references when pointers seem potent in this area?

It is less a matter of potency and more a matter of semantics, and responsibility.

A pointer:

- may be *null*
- may mean that you need to take ownership of the object (ie, it was created by `new` and *you* have to dispose of it)

A reference has none of those issues, so it is **simpler**. And *simplicity is good*. So when you do not need the power of a pointer, spare yourself its woes and use a reference.